# Workarounds for fluid motion blur in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation, motion-blur

cycles doesn't support **generate speed vectors** for fluids yet. Also, deformation motion blur does not work with fluids either.
Does anybody know of a workaround to this? Is it somehow possible to achieve a result with motion blur when rendering a fluid animation in cycles?

Comment: I've actually found a workaround in [another post here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/449/how-can-you-use-vector-blur-in-cycles-with-fluids).