# Can I use subframes to fake motion blur in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, motion-blur

I'm importing a sequence of OBJ files, then rendering the sequence. I would like to add motion blur to this sequence. The software that exports the sequence of OBJ files has the ability to export "subframes", or frames in between whole-number frames, essentially exporting the sequence in slow-motion (temporal supersampling).

So far, the best solution I can think of is to import the slow-motion OBJ sequence, render all of the frames, then average each set of subframes to get the final frames. This is really inconvenient, since I have to do two full passes to get the final frames: one for rendering each subframe, and another for combining each set of images.

From what I understand about Cycles motion blur, it randomly samples time values nearby the target frame number to generate the blur. This samples a continuous range of time values. In my case, I would be taking the time values from the continuous range and binning them into discrete subframe values. With enough subframes, the range (and the merged image) will appear smooth.

Can I ask Cycles what subframe it's rendering, and change the mesh to the right subframe for each time sample?

Comment: Don't think that Cycles can access an object set for mo blur, but you could try this solution http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/449/how-can-you-use-vector-blur-in-cycles-with-fluids

Comment: I found a workaround for this problem. It isn't exactly what I wanted, but it's way better than the solution I was about to implement. Here's the link to the blenderartists thread: https://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-245213.html and the link to the video tutorial: https://vimeo.com/36650120

Comment: @Justin Blender Artists: "***Oops! That page doesn’t exist or is private.***" This is why it's better to post an **answer** detailing what worked for you, than just a link that can rot.